# Saving fileName value into db mySQL using Plupload

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, filenames, plupload

The upload stage completely success with no problem. I just dont know how to store uploaded file's name to database. Heres my coding :

form.php

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plupload.full.js"></script>
 
<div id="uploader">
    <p><h6><strong>Upload Files:</strong></h6></p>
     
    <div id="filelist"></div><input type="hidden" id="hfileupload" name="hfileupload" />
    <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[ Select files ]</a>
    <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[ Upload files ]</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="hfilecounter" name="hfilecounter" value="0"/></div>
```

javascript from form.php

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
 
    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: 'flash',
        flash_swf_url: 'js/plupload.flash.swf',
        browse_button: 'pickfiles',
        url: 'upload.php'
    });
     
    uploader.init();
 
   uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        // loop through the files array
        for (var i in files) {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + files[i].id + '">' + files[i].name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(files[i].size) + ') <b></b></div>';}
    });
     
    uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
        document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
 document.getElementById("#hfileupload").val(file.target_name+"@"+file.name);
    });
     
 uploader.bind('FileUploaded',function(up, file, Response){
  if((Uploader.total.uploaded + 1) == Uploader.files.length){
   var myfilename = encodeURIComponent(File.name);
  };
 })
  
    uploader.bind('Error', function(up, args) {
        alert(args.code + ': ' + args.message);
    });
     
    document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
        uploader.start();
    };
 
//]]>
</script>
```

and default upload.php from plupload itself.

And I want save filename values into database with table named 'form' column named 'file'.

Comment: Where's the php code?

Comment: from form.php given. I just show the part of it that related to upload process

Comment: There's just js code, not actual php